# Issue while creating index in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create an index in Oracle on table QueueData and on field XYZ which is one of the nodes of XMLTYPE column TEXT.

My query is:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_QUEUE_XYZ ON QUEUEDATA (extractValue(TEXT, '//XYZ')) TABLESPACE "PSAPD"
```

But it is giving me following error:

```
ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node
```

I can't understand what is wrong here. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of the extractValue points to more then one node, it should return only one node, so if you have multiple tags "XYZ" it will return all of them if you use XYZ[1] only the first will be returned.

See:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Yes, there are multiple XYZ. so how can I create index on all of them?

Comment: instead of using a function based index you should use an xmlindex (especially if you are in v11): create index IX_QUEUE_XYZ ON QUEUEDATA (TEXT) INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLIndex;

Comment: When I'm trying the query: create index IX_QUEUE_XYZ ON QUEUEDATA (TEXT) INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLIndex; , it says : ORA-29833: indextype does not exist

Comment: check if if exists in DBA_INDEXTYPES, the column OWNER will tell you which user to use instead of XDB, if does not exist at all you might need to review your installation.